# Access controller in JavaFX and then execute a function from another class

Tags: java, javafx

So when i try to run the java code i get the error

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0

LoginController.java

```
public class LoginController {

    public void onSessionLoginAction() {
        //I have some functions here so i just minimize a bit of the code
        loginUser();
    }

    public void loginUser() {
        Init.getInstance().hideWindow("login"); // Error <---
        Init.getInstance().setEnabled(true);    // Error <---
        Init.getInstance().run();               // Success <--
    }
}
```

Init.java

```
public abstract class Init extends Application {

    private static Init instance;
    private boolean isEnabled = false;
    private Timer timer;

    public void initialize(Stage stage) {
        instance = this;

        // Login with session if you can :) Success to run this code here
        timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            FXMLLoader loader = loginWindow.getFxmlLoader();
            LoginController loginController = loader.<LoginController>getController();
            loginController.onSessionLoginAction(); //This runs the session on LoginController.java
            timer.stop();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean flag) {
        isEnabled = flag;
    }

    public static Init getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    public abstract void run();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either run your code in

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
        loginController.onSessionLoginAction();
    }
});
```

or use [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) instead of a `Timer`.

Comment: Omg thanks, i did try a similar code to yours but it did not work. But this works :)

Comment: @8803286 The issue is that all stuff that does something with the GUI is supposed to run on the GUI thread. When you are starting a timer, it will run on a different thread. This method allows you to run stuff on the GUI thread from elsewhere. A `Timeline` is sort of a JavaFX timer and is run on the GUI thread too.